# I am trying to set the depth level for certificate chain verification

Tags: lua

I am trying to use

```
store = require "openssl.x509.store"
```

So that I can set the depth level of certificate chain verification.
However `store.depth()` function is not accessible.

Comment: what's the error message? please read  [ask]

Comment: I am not getting any error message, the depth() is not available for me.

Comment: and how do you know that depth() is not available? did you print store.depth and it is nil?

Comment: I just cheked the below document : https://zhaozg.github.io/lua-openssl/modules/x509.store.html. Can you please give me the syntax to print the depth and set the depth to store.

Comment: I am printing as : print(store.depth), this is giving me nil.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference I understand that you first have to create an instance of the x509_store class using the new function. depth is not a member of the store library but of the x509_store class.

https://zhaozg.github.io/lua-openssl/modules/x509.store.html

Try

```
store = require "openssl.x509.store"
local myStore = store.new({})
print(myStore.depth)
```

and see if this is `nil`.

Comment: The same issue I am facing, myStore.depth is giving nil.

Comment: We are using openssl.so, we are not using lua-openssl library provided by 3rd party
local openssl_store = require "openssl.x509.store"
  local ca_ossl_store = openssl_store.new();
    print("Inspect ca_ossl_store : ",inspect(getmetatable(ca_ossl_store)))

Comment: By the below logs, we understand that openssl store has only 3 methods, no depth method. We are not sure of addDefaults method, what it does.So, will be of great help if you can confirm whether addDefaults method can help in setting depth.

Logs:
[lua] handler.lua:33: do_authentication(): Inspect ca_ossl_store : {
  __gc = <function 1>,
  __index = {
    add = <function 2>,
    addDefaults = <function 3>,
    verify = <function 4>
  },